# Toggle numbering method for theorem-like environments depending on nesting in a section or subsection

Tags: numbering, theorems, programming

I have been thinking of letting the sections determine the numbering style of theorems and such, in the following sense. If there are subsections, the enumeration should be `section.subsection.number`, for example "1.1.1 Theorem". If there are no subsections, it should be `section.number`, like "2.1 Theorem". My guess is that a little if-clause is all it takes, but I have never done any real programming in latex, and would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there's a theorem after the first section-level header, the theorem's "number" should presumably be "1.1". Suppose a `\subsection` directive is encountered next (yielding "1.1" as the subsection's number), followed by another theorem. Should this theorem's number be "1.1.2" (because it's the second theorem below section "1", or should it be "1.1.1" (because it's the first theorem under subsection "1.1")? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can condition on whether you're at the `\section` or `\subsection` level by looking at the value of the `subsection` counter. If it's 0 - done when you issue `\section` - you're within a `\section`, otherwise it is assumed you're in a `\subsection`.

Additionally, you can reset the `theorem` counter with every issue of `\section` or `\subsection` using [`chngcntr`](//ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr)'s `\counterwithin*{theorem}{<sec unit>}` macro. The starred version doesn't change the counter representation; you're doing that manually using conditionals, as mentioned in the first paragraph.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,chngcntr}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\counterwithin*{theorem}{section}
\counterwithin*{theorem}{subsection}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
    \thesection
  \else
    \thesubsection
  \fi
  .\arabic{theorem}%
}

\begin{document}

See Theorems~\ref{thm:first} and \ref{thm:second}.

\section{First section}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:first}\end{theorem}

\subsection{First subsection}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:second}\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}\end{theorem}

\subsection{Second subsection}

\begin{theorem}\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}\end{theorem}

\section{Second section}

\begin{theorem}\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```